# Does filtering a DataTable without a sort parameter preserve original order?

Tags: c#, sorting, .net-4.0, datatable, datatable.select

Per title, if I have a [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with columns for `ID` and `Name`, pre-sorted by name,  and I issue a call such as

```
    DataRow[] matchingRows = dataTable.Select("ID = " + filterID);
```

(i.e. without specifying a sort) will my array reliably come back in the table's order?

(And before you ask in comments *have you **tried** it?*, I'm not looking for unit-test results that consider every corner case in The Subdivision Escher Built, but documentation/proof that explains expected behavior, since [MSFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/way3dy9w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) [attempts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk13kdh0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) ain't gettin it done.)

Comment: I can't find any references to a "default" order for a `DataTable` anywhere. However since it exposes itself as an `IList` of sorts, I think it's safe to assume that the ordering is fixed and will not be random. And I see no reason why `Select()` or any other method  would want to randomize the order if the sort order was left unspecified. Though, that's not to say that the order wouldn't change if rows were added or removed, that could very well happen. There's no mention of order for that either though.

Comment: At least with the [`DataView.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort.aspx) property, it mentions that the order will be based on the index of the row in the `DataTable`. With this dependency on the order provided by the table, I would think that's enough to reliably say that the order would be fixed.

Comment: @JeffMercado Yes, sorry, I should have specified that (at least for the sake of argument) the `DataTable` can be considered read-only. Do you mean by your IList remark plus the "order provided by the table" comment that the index values of the filtered results' rows should be unchanged? If so, that is something I could probably test/prove.

Comment: My point ultimately is that the order in which a `DataTable` returns anything isn't really specified. But if the implementation was at all sane (which I would expect being part of the framework), it _should_ be safe to assume that it will always be in the order you get when viewing the `Rows` property.

Answer (score 1):

If your DataTable has a PrimaryKey then Select will use its index even if your rows aren't sorted that way.

Here is a LinqPad example that demonstrates it.

```
void Main()
{
            DataTable table = new DataTable("Demo");
            table.Columns.Add("PK", typeof(Int32));
            table.Columns.Add("Sequence", typeof(Int32));

            table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { table.Columns["PK"] };

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var newRow = table.NewRow();
                newRow["PK"] = 10 - i;
                newRow["Sequence"] = i;
                table.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }

            table.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new { PK = x["PK"], Sequence = x["Sequence"] }).Dump();
            table.Select().Select(x => new { PK = x["PK"], Sequence = x["Sequence"] }).Dump();
}
```